# How to show that the set of all direct hyperbolic transformation is closed under composition?

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

My work:

let $M_1 = J \frac{z-m}{1-\bar m  z}, M_2 = K \frac{z-n}{1-\bar n z} $ where $|J|,|K| = 1$ .$n,m \in {\mathscr d} $ then I simplified a bit and got $M_1 \circ M_2  = JK \frac {(z-n) - m(1-\bar n z)}{1 - \bar n z - \bar m k (z-n)} $. not sure how to continue from here

Comment: Have you tried collecting like terms and factoring out $z$-coefficients?